# eclipse not related with android safe uninstallable software

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a fairly old computer, and to speed up and reduce the eclipse ram used, I would remove all the software and Pugin who do not serve the development of Android applications from eclipse
Right now I have installed

- Equinox p2 (core function, CPR management, more ...)
- Eclipse csv (client, resource)
- Eclipse Help (dev resource, system)
- Eclipse PDE Plugin developer resource
- Eclipse RCP
- EMF (code, common, UI)
- Marketplace client
- Tracer for opengl es

And of course, Eclipse and Android related software. Which of these can I safely remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the EMF(Eclipse Modeling Framework Project (EMF)) because is a modeling entity framework and is not necessary for android development.

You can find more info here : [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't say exactly, Unfortunately, if android plugin depends on one element of other plugins. It may require to download lots of things. Even if you won`t use these things from the ADT plugin.

That said, there are couple of ways to reduce your eclipse installation. You can try to install a barebone bundle of eclipse with only minimal things. Then install the ADT plugin. It will take care of installing required plugins.

Or here's the risky way. Remove everything you want. I'm not so sure about that but I'm pretty sure that eclipse will tell you to remove every plugins that depend on the thing you want to delete. Anyway this method isn't perfect because you may delete things that are needed and unrelated to eclipse.

Keep in mind that in the packages you listed there should be sub packages and not all of them may be required or installed. And that eclipse by itself is kind of a BEAFY IDE